# Running an apache container on a port > 1024

Tags: apache, kubernetes, httpd.conf

I've built a docker image based on [httpd:2.4](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd). In my k8s deployment I've defined the following `securityContext`:

```
securityContext:
  privileged: false
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 431
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

In order to get this container to run properly as non-root apache needs to be configured to bind to a port > 1024, as opposed to the default 80. As far as I can tell this means editing `Listen 80` in `httpd.conf` to `Listen {Some port > 1024}`.

When I want to run the docker image I've build normally (i.e. on default port 80) I have the following port settings:

- deployment

  - `spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort`: 80
- service

  - `spec.ports[0].targetPort`: 80
  - `spec.ports[0].port`: 8080
- ingress

  - `spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.servicePort`: 8080

Given these settings the service becomes accessible at the host url provided in the ingress manifest. Again, this is without the changes to `httpd.conf`. When I make those changes (using `Listen 8000`), and add in the `securityContext` section to the deployment, I change the various manifests accordingly:

- deployment

  - `spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort`: 8000
- service

  - `spec.ports[0].targetPort`: 8000
  - `spec.ports[0].port`: 8080
- ingress

  - `spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.servicePort`: 8080

Yet for some reason, when I try to access a URL that should be working I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. Have I set the ports correctly? Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

#### Check if pod is Running

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl logs pod_name
```

#### Check if the URL is accessible within the pod

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- bash
$ curl http://localhost:8000
```

If the above didn't work, check your httpd.conf.

#### Check with the service name

```
kubectl exec -it <ingress pod_name> -- bash
$ curl http://svc:8080
```

You can check ingress logs too.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to get this container to run properly as non-root apache
>   needs to be configured to bind to a port > 1024, as opposed to the
>   default 80

You got it, that's the hard requirement in order to make the apache container running as non-root, therefore this change needs to be done at container level, not to Kubernetes' abstracts like Deployment's Pod spec or Service/Ingress resource object definitions. So the only thing left in your case, is to build a custom httpd image, with listening port > 1024. The same approach applies to the [NGINX](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#complex-configuration) Docker containers.

One key information for the 'containerPort' field in Pod spec, that you are trying to manually adjust, and which is not so apparent. It's there primarily for informational purposes, and does not cause opening port on container level. According Kubernetes API [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#container-v1-core):

> Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being
>   exposed. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address
>   inside a container will be accessible from the network. Cannot be updated.

I hope this will help you to move on